# Formally what is an unlabeled graph? I have no problem defining labeled graphs with set theory, but can't do the same here.

Tags: graph-theory, notation, set-theory, foundations

My only guess is maybe you could define an unlabeled graph as the isomorphism class of all labeled graphs. Of course unless we are using something stronger then $\text{ZFC}$ this won't make any sense as we are now working with essentially a "set of all sets", even if you restrict the vertex labeling to a certain class of sets say $\mathbb{N}$ you wont be able to represent graphs of an arbitrary cardinality. Anyway if someone could give me a definition in terms of some axiomatization of set theory I'd be grateful.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're saying. However it seems the first part of your definition sounds basically like how I defined labeled graphs set theoretically. I'm asking about unlabeled graphs in particular because I've seen notation like this $K_{m,n}$ for a complete bi-pirate graph, and it's unclear to me how they are defining this.

Comment: The standard usage is that when someone says “labelled graph” they mean “graph” (a set with a binary relation on it); when they say “unlabelled graph” they mean “isomorphism class”. If someone uses the term “unlabelled”  in a lecture, you can amuse yourself by asking them to write down a definition, without using a drawing. Or just ask them what is vertex in an unlabelled graph.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil So my first approach in the question is the right one?

Comment: The convention described by @ChrisGodsil is standard in combinatorics. For example, the number of unlabeled simple graphs on $3$ vertices is $4$, whereas the number of labeled graphs on a specified set of $3$ vertices is $8$. The set-vs.-class issue with isomorphism classes can be handled by standard tricks, for example by using only those graphs whose sets of vertices are initial segments of the ordinal numbers. That's more than enough graphs to include representatives of all isomorphism classes (assuming the axiom of choice, but without AC there's still Scott's trick).

Comment: @MorganRodgers I'm not sure whats being said. So an unlabeled graph is the isomorphic class of graphs?

Comment: I was unaware of that; I've deleted my previous comments.

Comment: So would it make sense to write $G$ is a labeled complete bipartite graph iff $\exists (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}^2:G\in K_{m,n}$ since $K_{m,n}$ is an isomorphic class of labeled graphs.

Answer (score 6):

As Noah says, usually an unlabeled simple graph would be a set $V$ whose elements we think of as vertices, together with an irreflexive symmetric binary relation on $V$ (or alternatively a set of 2-element subsets of $V$), which tells us which vertices are connected to each other.

It looks like you're objecting that this implicitly produces a labeling for the vertices, namely whichever the elements of $V$ are.

But the point of "unlabeled" is not that *we cannot possibly distinguish* between the vertices, but that we *decide not to care*. More precisely, "unlabeled" means that when we speak about *isomorphisms* of graphs we're not going to demand that the isomorphism preserves the names of vertices.

This holds in particular when we speak about whether two graphs are "the same" -- which almost always *implicitly* means "the same up to isomorphism".

That's not particular to graphs, by the way, but is a general phenomenon for all kinds of abstract structures in mathematics. For example in group theory we may say that "there is exactly one group of order $3$", again implicitly "up to isomorphism". When we say so, we don't care that that there are many ways to realize this group, such as with addition of residue classes modulo $3$, or as composition of even permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$.

For technical reasons, speaking about entire isomorphism classes of graphs (or groups) is not in favor, because it doesn't lend itself well to formalization in ZFC set theory. In contrast, it is standard and unproblematic to have "the same" implicitly include "up to isomorphism".

---

By the way, typically with a *labeled* graph one wouldn't use the elements of $V$ directly as labels either, because one often wants to be able to apply some or all of the labels to more than one vertex.

Comment: I don't understand then why define notation like $V(G)$ to describe the set of vertices? I see the same problem for $E(G)$ as without $V(G)$ we can't distinguish them either.

Comment: @user3865391: It's often convenient when writing down arguments to have a way to refer to a graph by a single letter, and have notation for speaking of the particular components of it. I don't need that here, but the definitions I present are not in conflict with _also_ using such notation.

Comment: Note that when we say $V(G)$ the $G$ does _not_ stand for an isomorphism class of graphs, but for a single concrete graph. (Sometimes, such as when you're given a graph as a drawing, you're expected to make your own choice of concrete representation of the drawing, in some consistent way that makes sense).